# How to omit rows with a value contained in a separate vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector of values and a data frame.

I would like to filter out the rows of the data frame which contain (in specific column) any of the values in my vector.

I'm trying to figure out if a person in the survey has a child who was also questioned in the survey - if so I would like to remove them from my data frame.

I have a list of respondent IDs, and vectors of mother/father personal IDs. If the ID appears in the mother/father column I would like to remove it.

```
df <- data.frame(ID= c(101,102,103,104,105), Name = (Martin, Sammie, Reg, Seamus, Aine)
vec <- c(103,105,108,120,150)
```

Output should be a dataframe with three rows - Martin, Sammie, Seamus.

```
ID   Name
1 101 Martin
2 102 Sammie
3 104 Seamus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[!(df$ID %in% vec), ] # Or subset(df, !(ID %in% vec))

#    ID   Name
# 1 101 Martin
# 2 102 Sammie
# 4 104 Seamus
```

*Data*

```
df <- data.frame(ID= c(101,102,103,104,105), Name = c("Martin", "Sammie", "Reg", "Seamus", "Aine"))
vec <- c(103,105,108,120,150)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df%>%
filter(!ID %in% vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create this as a data.table (and load data.table package, and fix the errors in the example data):

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(ID= c(101,102,103,104,105), Name = c("Martin", "Sammie", "Reg", "Seamus", "Aine"))
vec <- c(103,105,108,120,150)

# solution, slightly different from base R
df[!(ID %in% vec)]
```

Data.table is likely going to run a bit quicker than base R so very useful with large datasets. Microbenchmarking with a large dataset using base R, tidyverse and data.table shows data.table to be a bit quicker than tidyverse and a lot faster than base.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 10000000

df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1:n), "Name" = sample(LETTERS, size = n, replace = TRUE))

dt <- data.table(df)

vec <- sample(1:n, size = n/10, replace = FALSE)

microbenchmark(dt[!(ID %in% vec)], df[!(df$ID %in% vec),], df%>% filter(!ID %in% vec))
```